# Create widget programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview

As far as I understand, android widgets need RemoteViews, instead of View, like activities.

My question: is there any way to completely avoid xml, and build the whole layout with java code?

Alternative question: can I somehow retrieve a View, like I would use `findViewById(int)`? For example: `LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.xxx);` This way I could access the base layout, and manipulate however I want to.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add your custom view using `remoteViews.addView(viewId, nestedView)`

Comment: I was looking at that, probably that's what I will have to work with..

Comment: It will help u.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#addView%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there any way to completely avoid xml, and build the whole layout with java code?

No, sorry. `RemoteViews` relies heavily on layout XML resources. While there is an `addView()` method, it turns around and adds another `RemoteViews`, and that puts you right back where you started from.

> can I somehow retrieve a View, like I would use findViewById(int)?

No, because there is no `View` in your process. You configure the widgets via the various setter methods on `RemoteViews`.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, the `RemoteViews` is kind of a "replacement" of `View` in AppWidget context? I see that I can use `setTextViewText(int, CharSequence)` to set the displayed text, but can I retrieve it, like `getTextViewText()`? Unfortunately, there is no such method. Sorry if the questions are trivial or lame, I just started to learn it a few hours ago. :)

Comment: @hundeva: "the RemoteViews is kind of a "replacement" of View in AppWidget context?" -- it is a serialized set of commands for another process to define `Views` for the app widget. "but can I retrieve it, like getTextViewText()?" -- no. The app widget API is write-only.

Comment: @CommonsWare Any idea how [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kustom.widget&hl=en) manage to do the impossible?

Comment: @Pedram: Presumably, they are creating and showing bitmaps, or composing an app widget from a series of smaller layouts using `addViews()`. Either of those would seem to fit what that app offers, and I would bet they're going with the bitmap route, given their described feature set. If you have additional concerns in this area, ask a separate Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

You can take Linear Layout pragmatically like
`LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);`

also you can add its chilld using

```
Button mButton = new Button(this);
```

mLinearLayout.addView(mButton);

```
setContentView(mLinearLayout);
```

Comment: this is true for any Activity, however, you can't do this when working with `AppWidgetProvider`